# How to replace a character in array by the character received from another php page

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a problem on replacing the character in array by character receive from another page through Ajax.

```
href="show.php?q=1";
```

when user clicks this link it goes to:

show.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT mname FROM BClassroom WHERE slno='".$q."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $n = $name = strtoupper($row['mname']);
    }

    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($name); $i++){
        switch($name[$i]){
            case 'A':
                    $name[$i] = "A";
                  //  echo 'A'." ";
                    break;
            case 'E':
                    $name[$i] = "E";
                  //  echo 'E'." ";
                    break;
            case 'I':
                    $name[$i] = "I";
                   // echo 'I'." ";
                    break;
            case 'O':
                    $name[$i] = "O";
                  //  echo 'O'." ";
                    break;
            case 'U':
                    $name[$i] = "U";
                   // echo 'U'." ";
                    break;
            case ' ':
                    $name[$i] = "/";
                   // echo "/"." ";
                    break;
            default:
                    $name[$i] = "_";
                   // echo "_"." ";
                    break;
        }

    }
    echo "<p id='datatbl'>$name</p>";
?>

<fieldset>
<legend>START THE GUESS</legend>
<div>
    <?php
        $consonant = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
          $len = strlen($consonant);
            for($j=0;$j<$len;$j++){         ?>  
                <button name='CharCheck' id="sahil" onclick=checkBollyChar(this.value) value='<?php echo $consonant[$j] ?>'><?php echo $consonant[$j] ?></button>
        <?php   }   
    ?>
    <p><span id="datatbl"></span></p>
</div>
<button onclick="showResult(this.value)" value="<?php echo $n; ?>">Show Result</button>
</fieldset>

<script>
   function checkBollyChar(str){
            if(str==""){
               document.getElementById("datatbl").innerHTML="";
               return;
            }else{
                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
                       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                              }
               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status ==200){
                        document.getElementById("datatbl").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
               }
               xmlhttp.open("GET","handler.php?q="+str,true);
               xmlhttp.send();
            }
      buttonHide();
   }
</script>
<script>
   function showResult(str){
            if(str==""){
               document.getElementById("datatbl").innerHTML="";
               return;
            }else{
                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
                       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                              }
               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status ==200){
                        document.getElementById("datatbl").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
               }
               xmlhttp.open("GET","Result.php?q="+str,true);
               xmlhttp.send();
            }
   }   
</script>
```

when user clicks on button `name="charCheck"`, it should replace the `"_"` with the character if it matches with actual character in the word.

for `"JURASSIC"`, it shows `"_ U _ A _ _ I _ _"` only vowels, so when user clicks button `"J"` then `"_"` in first place should be replace by `"J"`.

thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem, if the problem is on PHP side paste only the exact section of your php code you are stuck at, if is on JS, the same thing.

Comment: Initially page shows only vowels of a movie name i.e for "GODZILLA" it shows "_ O _ _ I _ _ A". then i created buttons containing all the consonants so, when the user clicks on that button suppose "G", then the first "_" should be replaced by G and new String should be "G O _ _ I _ _ A".  the button calls ajax function to check the character from another page. All i want is to replace the "_"  alphabets if the user clicks on right alphabet button. thanks